# Unique IP addresses over internet?

Tags: networking, ip-address, ipv4

This might be a silly question but I'm wondering, if we have only 4 billion of IPV4  addresses available over the internet, and still most of the devices uses IPV4. So how is this possible? And if I'm using my mobile then how he got its unique IP address on the internet?

Answer (score 3):

This is really basic and quick overview.

There is now a new IP standard [IPv6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6) which increases the amount of IP addresses available dramatically. Quick google on [IPv6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6) will give you the exact number of addresses [IPv6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6) provides.

But before IPv6, IPv4 was running out. So what they did was set aside 3 different ip address ranges ([IPv4 Private Address Ranges](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network)) ranges for use on 'private' networks and they combined the use of these networks with '[Network Address Translation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation)' ([NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation)) which allows private networks to share 1 public IP address.

For example 1000 computers could all be on the same private network but only require 1 public IP address. This saves 999 Public IP addresses because all those computers share the same public address.

NAT is usually implemented on the [network gateway](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gateway_(telecommunications)) (usually a router).
Heres a diagram which conveniently shows an example of NAT:

[image]

Diagram from : http://www.firewall.cx/networking-topics/network-address-translation-nat/227-nat-concepts.html

I don't have much experience with mobile networks but if the network isn't using [IPv6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6) to give unique public IPs to each phone on it, it would have to be using some form of NAT. So a telecommunications company might be given a bunch of public IP address they can use and then use NAT to share the use of those IPs with 1000s of customers.

It is also worth noting that NAT can be used with IPv6.

Answer (score 1):

Ya that a basic one.

You might have heard about DHCP(Dynamic Host Control Protocol) which assigns IP address to computers dynamically from the available pool of IP's.

Lets start with IP address assignment for a Enterprise/mid/small company they do have some public IP assigned from ISP's and the computers in their network get their unique ip's via a router that's the gateway to the Internet world .

Lets say 100 Ip's are there with ISP so they provide that IP's to may be individual or some company  and that company may have 100's of computers gets IP's via NAT(Network Address Translation). So another 100 computers have unique IP's available on the local network. Suppose 1 computer making a google search request it will have its local IP till its local network but when that request reach google servers the local IP is resolved by the public IP which was assigned by the ISP to that company and this is done by NAT.

On the bigger picture where our cellular networks work is done by CGN NAT (Carrier-grade NAT or Carrier-grade Network Address Translation). One example is NAT444, in this a particular residential networks, are configured with private network addresses that are translated to public IPv4 addresses by middlebox network address translator devices embedded in the network.